# Apparent Lag with Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, forms, graphics

### The Situation

As a side hobby project, I decided to venture down simulating an incredibly basic reality. My idea was to create a simple universe where the objects inside would interact based on stuff like position or velocity. One would be able to add a force to an object to make it move. So to display this 'universe' I had to learn Window's Forms. Hence, my knowledge around the topic is limited. I created a timer object, so that after every period of time, I would call the render of the universe to generate a bitmap and set a picturebox to that. To render the universe, I would simply render each object onto a bitmap hence creating almost a collage of objects.

To test this, I created a universe, and added a block. At every update of the image, I would add a force to the block based on the keypresses. However, what I encountered was that the program had a lot of visual 'lag'. At times it would run very smoothly, but seconds later it would freeze for half a second, then resume working again. It was somewhat noticeable, although not incredibly bad. Regardless, this is something I want to fix, and/or at least know why this happens to become a better programmer.

I have already researched fixes, but to no success. I included stuff like double buffer and disposing of the graphics and bitmap objects after use, but this had little to no effect.

[Just the image of what the forms displays - nothing intersting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wt6N.png)

### The Question

What is causing this 'lag' and what can I do to fix it?

### The Code

```
class Block 
{
    ...

    public Tuple<float, float> Dimension { get; }
    public Tuple<float, float> Position { get; set; }

    ...

    public void Render(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            int x = bitmap.Width / 2;
            int y = bitmap.Height / 2;
            //g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 500, 500);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkCyan, Position.Item1 + x - Dimension.Item1 / 2, Position.Item2 + y - Dimension.Item2 / 2,
                Dimension.Item1, Dimension.Item2);
        }

    }

}
class Universe
{
    ...

    public List<IObject> Objects;
    public Tuple<int, int> Dimensions;

    ...

    public Bitmap RenderUniverse()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Dimensions.Item1, Dimensions.Item2);
        foreach (var obj in Objects)
        {
            obj.Render(bitmap);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

}

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Universe Universe;
        const int SPF = 50; //MILLISECONDS TILL NEXT UPDATE
        public Form1()
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Tick += Update;
            timer.Interval = SPF;
            timer.Start();
            ...
            InitializeComponent();
            DoubleBuffered = true;
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(Universe.Dimensions.Item1, Universe.Dimensions.Item2);
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(Universe.Dimensions.Item1, Universe.Dimensions.Item2);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;
        }

        public void Update(object o, EventArgs args)
        {
        ...
            if (pictureBox1.Equals(null))
                pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = Universe.RenderUniverse();
            pictureBox1.Refresh();

        }
    }
```

## Edit:

I have now taken away the picturebox and used OnPaint. However, this has not solved the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PictureBox resources release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972162/picturebox-resources-release)

Comment: Nothing obvious from the code.  This is the kind of program where the garbage collector almost never runs.  It uses vast amounts of unmanaged memory but the drawing objects are too small to give the GC any work.  Do keep an eye on memory usage and check if you can correlate the GC performance counters visible in perfmon.exe with the slowdown.  Keep the bitmap around instead of re-creating it repeatedly, use Graphics.Clear() to re-initialize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use a picture box, but instead directly draw on the surface. Either draw directly on the form or insert a control used as frame (e.g. a Panel) and draw on that.

The you should draw in the Paint event. Let's draw on the form itself:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int x = ClientSize.Width / 2;
    int y = ClientSize.Height / 2;
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(
        Pens.DarkCyan,
        _currentBlock.Position.Item1 + x - _currentBlock.Dimension.Item1 / 2,
        _currentBlock.Position.Item2 + y - _currentBlock.Dimension.Item2 / 2,
        _currentBlock.Dimension.Item1,
        _currentBlock.Dimension.Item2);
}
```

Then you can trigger drawing whenever there is a change by calling the `Invalidate` method of the form or the control you are drawing on:

```
Invalidate();
```

This has the advantage that there can be no congestion, as Windows will only call `OnPaint` if it is not already painting.

If you want to force an immediate update, call `Refresh` instead:

```
Refresh();
```

---

Full example (uses `PointF` and `SizeF` structures from the namespace `System.Drawing` instead of tuples):

```
interface IObject
{
    SizeF Dimension { get; }
    PointF Position { get; set; }

    void Render(Graphics g, int x, int y);
}

class Block : IObject
{
    public PointF Position { get; set; }
    public SizeF Dimension { get; set; }

    public void Render(Graphics g, int x, int y)
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(
            Pens.DarkCyan,
            Position.X + x - Dimension.Width / 2,
            Position.Y + y - Dimension.Height / 2,
            Dimension.Width,
            Dimension.Height);
    }
}

public partial class frmPaintOnForm : Form
{
    private Timer _timer = new Timer();

    private IObject _currentObject;
    private List<IObject> _objects = new List<IObject> {
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(50,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF(10, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(50,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF(20, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(50,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF(20,10), Dimension = new SizeF(50,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF(20,20), Dimension = new SizeF(50,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF(20,30), Dimension = new SizeF(50,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF(10,30), Dimension = new SizeF(50,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0,30), Dimension = new SizeF(50,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0,20), Dimension = new SizeF(50,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0,20), Dimension = new SizeF(50,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(50,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(55,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(60,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(65,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(60,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(55,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(50,50) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(50,55) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(50,60) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(50,65) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(50,60) },
        new Block{ Position = new PointF( 0, 0), Dimension = new SizeF(50,55) },
    };
    private int _index;

    public frmPaintOnForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

        _timer.Interval = 17;
        _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Select the next object by cycling through the object list and trigger drawing
        _currentObject = _objects[_index];
        _index = (_index + 1) % _objects.Count;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_currentObject != null) {
            int x = ClientSize.Width / 2;
            int y = ClientSize.Height / 2;
            _currentObject.Render(e.Graphics, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you never call `OnPaint` directly. The operating system (Windows) takes care of this. By calling `Invalidate`, you just give a hint to Windows and Windows decides when and if `OnPaint` will be called. Windows can call it in many situations: When the form is opened or restored from being minimized, when another form on top of this one is removed, when the form is being resized and of course, if you requested it by calling `Invalidate` or `Refresh`. It may also call it to draw a miniature image of the form when hovering over the taskbar. Windows may also decide to leave out some calls if there is a congestion or if the form is not visible.

Comment: @Oliver_Jacot-Descombes How does the Paint event work. How do i call it?

Comment: You never call it. You call Invalidate() or Refresh(). Windows uses this as a hint and decides when to actually call OnPaint. Windows may also call it if you resize the form for instance.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this would allow each object to render? The onpaint only affects the form. How would i make it render each object from inside the object's class?

Comment: so does that mean that every time you do Invalidate, it triggers OnPaint?

Comment: I added a full example.

Comment: Okay i implemented this approach and it loads. However, it still 'lags'. Any other ideas?

Comment: There is an overlaod of `Invalidate` allowing you to specify which portion of the drawing surface to update. This requires a bit more logic (where was the old object, where is the new one, combine the 2 regions) but can speed up drawing.

Comment: By how much would you say? Im only drawing a small square at the moment, would this massivley affect this?

Comment: I made a working example and and don't experience lag. Posted the full example now.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your code which is trying to cleanup old images:

```
if (pictureBox1.Equals(null))
    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
pictureBox1.Image = Universe.RenderUniverse();
```

(particularly the first line) is not doing what you think it does. Your comment suggests you believe the first line:

> Checks to see if pictureBox1 has a bitmap already (i.e. it is the
>   first time i have rendered the universe)

But what it **actually** does is checks whether the `pictureBox1` is `null` (which it never is in the flow of your code).

To fix this, instead use:

```
var oldImage = pictureBox1.Image;
pictureBox1.Image = Universe.RenderUniverse();
oldImage?.Dispose();
```

Comment: This is not true. It is null at the very start

Comment: I disagree @RetAFVLib. `pictureBox` is never null when that code runs. `pictureBox1.Image` might be - but that is a different thing altogether. Give my code a try, see how you go.