# Update text in WinForms Label symmetrically from center

Tags: c#, winforms, label, text-alignment

How to update text in WinForms `Label` control symmetrically from the center if each line here is value update, not the single text, first shows "A", then "New" etc:

```
            A
           New
           Year
          Comes
          again 
        and again
        to spread 
      the spirit and
     Celebration have 
   a wonderful New Year 
 party and Happy New Year
    with joy and peace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a StringBuilder with the label's TextAlign property to MiddleCenter and AutoSize to true.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("A");
sb.AppendLine("New");
sb.AppendLine("Year");
sb.AppendLine("Comes");
sb.AppendLine("again");
sb.AppendLine("and again");
sb.AppendLine("to spread");
sb.AppendLine("the spirit and");
sb.AppendLine("Celebration have");
sb.AppendLine("a wonderful New Year");
sb.AppendLine("party and Happy New Year");
sb.AppendLine("with joy and peace");

Label l = new Label();
l.AutoSize = true;
l.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
l.Text = sb.ToString();

Controls.Add(l);
```

Answer (score 1):

A single label having `TextAlign = MiddleCenter` will do the trick. Just make sure you don't put extra space before or after each line of text:

```
label1.AutoSize = true;
label1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
label1.Text =
@"
A
New
Year
Comes
again
and again
to spread
the spirit and
Celebration have
a wonderful New Year
party and Happy New Year
with joy and peace
";
```

Comment: `label1.Text = "A";` then `label1.Text += "New\n";` or `label1.Text += "New"+Environment.NewLine;` and so on. If you also want a delay between adding lines of the text, you can do it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569988/3110834).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the labels `AutoSize` to false and let them have the same width and same left:

```
foreach(var lbl in labels)
{
    lbl.SuspendLayout();
    lbl.Left = 0;
    lbl.Width = 500;
    lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    lbl.ResumeLayout();
}
```

For getting all labels you can

```
var labels = parent.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
    //where parent is the container of the labels
    // note that this would select any other label on the container
```

You can also add them manually:

```
Label[] labels = new[] {label1, label2, ....};
```